# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and vice-versa

Tags: java, web, struts2

I need to develop an interceptor in struts 2 that has to redirect HTTP to HTTPS and vice-versa for all the actions. Therefore, it seems that the [plugin struts-ssl2-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-ssl-plugin/wiki/HowToUse) does not work for me because I cannot have two actions for different protocols (HTTP and HTTPS).

Note that I am able to detect on the interceptor if I am intercepting HTTP or HTTPS, through header parameters or through cookies.

I could not find anything else that could help me with this, so I ask if you know any other plugins or if you have done this or something similar or know any other way to do this.

I would be much appreciated for any help.

Regards